# Is there a way to insert checkboxes and text boxes in Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to be able to populate a table of user defined length with one column of check boxes and one column of text boxes. For example, the user will enter a number of rows in a text box on a page, click a button, and generate this table. Is this possible using VBA? I have done this in excel but is there something equivalent for Word?

Comment: Yes, word has the same function, you should test it yourself

Comment: Thanks! just found it.

Comment: In Stack Overflow, you should be posting some code that you want help with. Super User is for asking questions about how applications work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  --- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask